# Why won't Application.Exit() quit a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am working on learning Windows Forms with C# and have a bare bones application. I am trying to close it when the user selects File->Exit. I have an event handler attached to it and I have tried calling `Application.Exit()`, `Application.ExitThread()` and just closing the form. Nothing. It stays there. I'm not creating any other threads of any sort either.

Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Likely the event handler isn't being called. If you set a breakpoint is it hit? Post some code.

Comment: Does the application terminate properly when you press Alt+F4 with the form active?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to put a breakpoint in the event handler to see if it is being hit?

If so, the application won't exit if the window messages aren't being delivered (i.e. the UI thread is blocked). One way to test this is to call `Environment.Exit()` which is more brutal about forcing a close. If this succeeds, you can then figure out why `Application.Exit()` isn't working.

Comment: auto completion in VS screwed me up. I was assigning the delegate to another similarly named menu item.

Answer (score 5):

`Application.Exit` isn't the normal way to close a GUI application.  Use `form.Close` instead.

```
  private static void OnMenuClose_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
     Form dlg = ((Control) sender).FindForm();
     //dlg.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
     dlg.Close();
  }
```

Comment: It does if you do it to the main form.  If all other forms are children they will be destroyed automatically.

Comment: Note that the `FormClosing` event on any other forms or dialogs that are open are not called when using `form.Close()`. When using `Application.Exit()` you can "abort" the close request from the `FormClosing` event of any other form or dialog.